# Django template rendering extend tag incorrectly

Tags: django, django-templates

I have three Django templates:

1. base.html:
2. user_links.html
3. user_detail.html

I want user_links.html to extend base.html. Next, I want user_detail.html to extend user_links.html and base.html.

Here's base.html:

```
<head>
  <title>Cool App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Cool App</h1>
<div class="navbar">
<p>
    <a href="{% url 'home' %}">HOME</a> |
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">LOGOUT</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'login' %}">LOGIN</a>
{% endif %}</p>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
{% block pagination %}
{% endblock %}</div>
```

Here's user_links.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
Yellow
Pink
Green
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

And here's user_detail.html

```
{% extends "user_links.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h2>{{ object.username }}'s Profile</h2>
    {% if object.userprofile.bio %}
    {{ object.userprofile.bio }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

So when the browser renders user_detail.html, I want it to (i) show the stylesheet and navigation links from base.html, (ii) show the word Yellow, Pink, Green from user_links.html, (iii) and show the user's username and bio. But (ii) is not being rendered at all, though (i) and (iii) are correctly rendering.

How should the templates be set up so that I see (i), (ii) and (iii) in user_detail.html? Please advise.

*Note: all three templates reside in the same directory. I'm on Django 1.5*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extends a base.html template, no content not surrounded by {% block %} will be rendered at all.

You could create additional `{% block precontnet %}{% endblock %}` in `base.html`, and wraps Pink/Yellow/Red in `user_links.html`

Or you can put Pink/Yellow/Red in `{% block content %}` if `user_links.html` and use [{{ block.super }}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/) in `user_detail.html`

`links.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    Yellow
    Pink
    Green
{% endblock %}
```

`user_detail.html`

```
{% extends "user_links.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <h2>{{ object.username }}'s Profile</h2>
        {% if object.userprofile.bio %}
            {{ object.userprofile.bio }}
        {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks, works. Can you explain what's {{ block.super }}

Comment: Please, go to the link on {{ block.super }} and read the documentation. Django docs is awesome, and there is no better way to explain.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/

Comment: Didn't notice you had linked it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Place `div` after `</p>` in **base.html**

```
<h1>Cool App</h1>
<div class="navbar">
<p>
    <a href="{% url 'home' %}">HOME</a> |
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">LOGOUT</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'login' %}">LOGIN</a>
{% endif %}</p>
</div>
```

Try this in **user_links.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
Yellow
Pink
Green
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: No doesn't work. BTW I accidentally omitted writing </div> in the question statement, it's actually there. As for your recommendation for user_links.html, I've tried wrapping Yellow, Pink and Green in the block content tags before too, but nothing happens.